# Group by Sum and Count of Table Records Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

So i have a table with a listings which has various dates and amount.

```
e.g. 
Date               Amount 
2/1/2015           200
3/2/2015           300
7/2/2015           350
8/1/2015           400
```

I want to be able to write a query which returns the sum of the amount grouped by month.

```
So e.g. Jan 600, Feb 650
```

How do i do that in rails? Sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y - %b') AS the_date , 
  SUM(val_field) AS total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y - %b')
ORDER BY  DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y - %b');
```

Comment: can write this in rails query?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by and sum a table in rails as follows:

```
Model.sum(:amount, :group => 'MONTH("date_column")')
```

Here is a link with more information on ActiveRecord calculations: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html

Edit: Changed code to say `date_column` to be clearer

Comment: The `Month("date")` is a query specific to mysql. Also, `date` should be replaced by whatever your date column name is in your table. In addition you will need to replace `Model` and `amount` to the relevant names. I have changed the code to say `Month("date_column")` to be clearer